# How could I combine two hash maps of <String, Integer> to one HashMap of <HashMap<String, String>, Integer>?

Tags: java, java-8

HashMap<String1, Integer1> and HashMap<String2, Integer2> to HashMap<HashMap<String1,String2> , Integer1+Integer2>

Comment: Not to sound rude, but I think you need to brush up on your basic knowledge of Map construct. Because I'm really not sure what result you want here.

Comment: Can you post an example where you are facing problem

Answer (score 0):

see hashmap contains Map(Key, Value) so if you want to merge the hashmap then you are changing the key.
so if you want to add multiple keys then you can do it with

`Map<Map.Entry<String,String>, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();`

`map.put(Map.entry("onekey", "2nd Keys"), 0);`